# convert bash command to php imagick function

Tags: php

I'm new to imagick. any one can convert the following bash command to php imagick function.

```
convert black.jpg shirt_mask.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -evaluate add 30% \-alpha on -background "gray(50%)" -alpha background -alpha off tshirt_process.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be faster to just use php `exec` function in your case:

```
exec("convert black.jpg shirt_mask.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -evaluate add 30% \-alpha on -background "gray(50%)" -alpha background -alpha off tshirt_process.png");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php